# Username from session gets send with form in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, session, send

So here's the question. I recently started using ruby as a programming language and I was wondering how I could use name from a session (when someone is logged in) to get send with a form.

I installed devise and simple form hoping to get it done but it didn't work. My first thought was to use this bit of code to send the user with the form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :name, :placeholder => current_user %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit1 - Controller code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end
end
```

Comment: Your controller is incorrect. You are basically doing nothing in the controller.

Comment: So what bit of code could I use to put in there? Because I honestly don't know

Comment: take a look at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

In the **new** and **edit** action of the controller, you can assign the value current_user to the field, **name** of the object.

Something like:

```
# in New action
@controller = Controller.new
@controller.name = current_user.name
```

Comment: no in your controller. In new and edit actions.. show me your controller

Comment: class HomeController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end
    end